# set value from webview android app and retrieve it from javascript

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

Since javascript we will not be able to get the device id the alternative to identify the user we are planning to create an alternative method.

Our appraoch is
Storing a value as a webview cookie and using javascript to get that value.

What we are looking for is store some value in cookie in our webview app on andoird studio and then when the person clicks on a perticular link retrive that value using javascript.

We can take the device id or any random value and store in webbrowsers storage or any method you could suggest.

```
String deviceid = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
        Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JavascriptInterface** on Android side.

try like the below codes in your WebViewActivity or WebViewFragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        yourWebView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        yourWebView.addJavascriptInterface(JavaScriptInterface(), "YourWebViewBridgeCustomName")
}

private inner class JavaScriptInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun getDeviceId(): String {
        return yourGetDeviceIdLogic()
    }
}
```

Then, you can call above method from web side by below codes.

```
window.YourWebViewBridgeCustomName.getDeviceId();
```

Check below android document also.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)